# iOS - a custom class having reference to UIViewController object

Tags: ios, memory-management, retain, automatic-ref-counting

First of, I am using ARC and targeting iOS4+

I have a custom class that needs a reference to a custom UIViewController. 
Unless I have missunderstod something, having the property `retain` on that reference means that whenever my class destructs, the UIViewController destructs aswell? 
Or does it mean that both the appdelegate (which created the UIViewController) and my custom class needs to be deallocated in order for the UIViewController to be deallocated?

So I also read about `__unsafe_unretained` property. Can my custom class simply use that without complications to reference the UIViewController? Since the appdelegate would deallocate the UIViewController in the end anyway, there is no risk of a dangling pointer?

Thanks

EDIT: The custom class is a singleton object that will live through the entire process if it matters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object has a retain count that essentially determines whether or not it needs to stick around. In this case your AppDelegate has retained the UIViewController already (retain count of 1), but that does not mean that your custom class cannot also retain the UIViewController (retain count of 2). So your second scenario is closer to the truth: when your custom class destructs and releases the UIViewController the retain count will drop back to 1. Then, when the AppDelegate destructs and releases it the count will drop to 0 and the object will be destroyed.

To take this a step further, if inside of your custom class you assigned the UIViewController to another bult-in or custom class which also retained it the count would keep going up and then it would drop back as each of those objects in turn released its interest.

Comment: I see. Is there any downside to use retain in my custom class then? or should I still use __unsafe_unretain? I am basically accessing methods/variables from the UIViewController with the custom class

Comment: You should use retain. It does not hurt anything and is good practice even though your UIViewController is unlikely to be destroyed during the life of your custom class. Generally as long as your retain and release counts match (and you don't create a circular retain loop) you will be fine.

Comment: When I use my custom class to access methods and variables of the UIViewController, do I have to enclose them with @synchonrize as well?

Comment: Whether or not to use @synchronize is really a separate question. You may want to read up on [threading in Apple's docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/ThreadSafety/ThreadSafety.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000057i-CH8-SW1). As your class is a singleton, if you are working with multiple threads you are likely going to need to think about locking/@synchronize but it really depends on your exact scenario.